# Create with MATLAB several gamma distributions and print them to pdf

Tags: pdf, distribution

As the title already suggests, I want to plot several gamma distributions with different scape and shape parameters in different colors onto one plot and save the figure as pdf.

I have tried some things out but I am new to MATLAB and nothing really worked well..

Thanky you

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
figure(1)
hold all
grid on
% For the case of 3 curves:
plot(x1,gamma(x1),x2,gamma(x2),x3,gamma(x3))
xlabel('X Variable [Unit]')
ylabel('Gamma Function [-]')
title('Gamma Function of the three variables x1, x2, x3')
legend('First','Second','Third','location','best')
saveas(figure(1), 'nameofpicture.pdf');
```

Hope it works fine, I'm a Matlab user until a long time and this is a good solution :-)

Bye

M.L.C.